# spring data mongodb jpa find by id with composite id

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I am using mongodb with springboot and I've got an entity with a custom `_id`, like so (in Java):

```
@Document(collection="myEntity")
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    private MyId id;
    private String field1;
    // getters, setters
    public static class MyId {
        private long field1;
        private String field2;
        private String field3;
        // getters, setters
    }

}
```

In a mongo repository I have a `findById(MyId)` method that I would like to use to find an entity by its id. The default `save(MyEntity)` method works fine, saving the entity such that the `MyId#id` field is wrapped in a `NumberLong`.

So for example the mongodb query

```
db.myEntity.find()
```

will return a list of entities like

```
{
  "_id": {
    "field1": NumberLong("1"),
    "field2": "a",
    "field3": "b"
  },
  "field1": "aa"
}
```

On the other hand, with debug logging of mongodb queries enabled, the `findById` method shows

> findOne using query  `{ "_id": { "field1": "$numberLong": "1", "field2": "a", "field3": "b" }, "field1": "aa" }`

In the mongo shell:

Running `db.myEntity.find({ "_id": { "field1": { "$numberLong": "1" }, "field2": "a", "field3": "b" }, "field1": "aa" })` gives no results.

Running `db.myEntity.find({ "_id": { "field1": new NumberLong("1"), "field2": "a", "field3": "b" }, "field1": "aa" })` returns a result.

How can I fix this such that the `findById(MyId)` query method works (returns the result I expect for the given id)?

Comment: [NumberLong](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/index.html#numberlong) is the shell representation - so it works fine in `mongo` shell. [$numberLong](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/index.html#bson.Int64) is the extended JSON representation for a _long_ number.

Comment: Hi @prasad_ thanks for your input. Maybe the question isn't clear. I mean, "how do I fix my entity such that the findById(MyId) query works with spring jpa? I've updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Are you using Spring Data MongoDB?

Comment: @prasad_ yes I am

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hopefully this can help someone. The jpa "find" works when specifying the `@org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query` like so:

```
@Query("{ '_id.field1': ?0, '_id.field2': ?1, '_id.field3': ?2}")
Optional<MyEntity> find(long field1, String field2, String field3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to override the `.toString()` at your custom Id class.
MongoDB has a different implementation of the `.toString()` from the Java one (which contains hashCode).